# "Facebook Public Profile" instead of app-Name in LikeBox

Tags: facebook-social-plugins, facebook-likebox

Since a few days, instead off the name of my app, die text-string "Facebook Public Profile" appears on the top of the like box of my app - the box itself is empty, only saying that i like this site.

Here is the iframe-code of the like box:

```
<iframe src="http://www.facebook.com/plugins/likebox.php?id=144416678913418&amp;width=292&amp;colorscheme=light&amp;show_faces=true&amp;stream=false&amp;header=true&amp;height=327" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" style="border:none; overflow:hidden; width:292px; height:427px;" allowTransparency="true"></iframe>
```

When i create a new box on http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like-box/, the correct box is created, but i don't have any likes. There where more than 1000 likes on the old box, it would be frustrating if they all are lost. So what can i do?

The app the like box is for: [politicaltest](http://apps.facebook.com/politicaltest)

Comment: Was the old like box pointing to an App Profile Page?  those were removed in February, so the Likes don't really point to anything

Comment: i'm wondering why there isn't any URL off the app in my old box code, is the box automatically pointed to the app profile page when there is only the ID? And is it possible to get the old like-count?

Comment: OK, ich got it, using `href=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.facebook.com%2Fpoliticaltest&amp;appId=144416678913418` instead of only the id fixes the problem. Thanks for helping!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. Using a secure URL (https//www.facebook.com/mypage) solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

As Fideri mentioned - using HTTPS protocol instead of HTTP solves the problem. Another thing to be noted - case sensitivity. https://www.facebook.com/heiaheiaheia - works, https://www.facebook.com/HeiaHeiaHeia - doesn't.

There's a bug on Facebook about this: https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/294214537324996?browse=search_4fa3f2c98bbef5d13178743

Answer (score 0):

I found another solution. it turned out we had set the age restrictions of our fb page to 18 or more. When we removed the age restriction, the like box started working.